# TypeORM one-to-many relation changes the original entity after binding relation

Tags: typescript, database, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I wanted to build a friend request system for my side project and I used Nestjs + TypeORM for the backend. However, every time I attempt to bind a `Friend` entity to a certain user, the `target` field of that `Friend` entity changes from the original target to the user I'm binding to. For example:

After I created the `Friend` entity and before binding it to the user object, it looks like follows:

```js
Friend {
  id: '31466acb-749e-43f0-be82-4ec4c08d8ff5',
  createdAt: 2023-03-04T04:35:23.576Z,
  target: User {
    id: 3,
    email: 'sandu@outlook.com',
    password: '$2a$10$/bVbxCmyFEfkPsqOvN0efePNLKYZjrFwfGJm1yTU3bICAS8q2MlcO',
    username: 'sandu',
    lastLoginAt: 2023-03-04T03:48:48.369Z,
    socketId: null,
    online: false
  }
}
```

But after I bind it to user `samzhangjy`, it changes to:

```js
Friend {
  id: '31466acb-749e-43f0-be82-4ec4c08d8ff5',
  createdAt: 2023-03-04T04:35:23.576Z,
  target: User {
    id: 1,
    email: 'samzhangjy@outlook.com',
    password: '$2a$10$ibwq2hCq3pbzrEitlhEHjeP0H5wklkEmsjtQ.0ZMO3jLWOR4RhxXC',
    username: 'samzhangjy',
    lastLoginAt: 2023-02-25T04:28:29.079Z,
    socketId: 'CDWGfFWCskfH-J3RAAAD',
    online: true
  }
}
```

And so when I query the friend list of each user, it always returns the wrong result.

My service code for adding friends:

```js
public async addFriend({ requestId }: AddFriendDto) {
  const request = await this.getFriendRequest(requestId, true);
  if (request.status !== FriendRequestStatus.ACCEPTED) {
    throw new ServiceException(
      'Friend request must be accepted to add the target user.',
      HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
    );
  }
  const senderToReceiverPreferences =
    await this.friendPreferencesRepository.save({
      nickname: request.senderSetNickname,
      permission: request.senderSetPermission,
    });
  const senderToReceiver = await this.friendRepository.save({
    preferences: senderToReceiverPreferences,
    target: request.target,
  });
  const t = await this.friendRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: senderToReceiver.id },
    relations: ['target'],
  });
  console.log(t);  // correct
  const receiverToSenderPreferences =
    await this.friendPreferencesRepository.save({
      nickname: request.targetSetNickname,
      permission: request.targetSetPermission,
    });
  const receiverToSender = await this.friendRepository.save({
    preferences: receiverToSenderPreferences,
    target: request.sender,
  });
  await this.dataSource
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(User, 'friends')
    .of(request.sender)
    .add(senderToReceiver.id);
  const sender = await this.userRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: request.sender.id },
    relations: ['friends', 'friends.target'],
  });
  console.log(sender.friends);  // incorrect
  const ta = await this.friendRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: senderToReceiver.id },
    relations: ['target'],
  });
  console.log(ta);  // incorrect
  const receiver = await this.userRepository.findOne({
    where: { id: request.target.id },
    relations: ['friends'],
  });
  receiver.friends.push(receiverToSender);
  await this.userRepository.save(receiver);
}
```

As it showed in the code, I have tried to use both `QueryBuilder` and the `.save` method, but both of them didn't work.

The `Friend` entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class Friend {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.friends)
  public target!: User;

  @OneToOne(() => FriendPreferences)
  @JoinColumn()
  public preferences!: FriendPreferences;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  public createdAt!: Date;
}
```

The `User` entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id!: number;

  @Column()
  public email!: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  public password!: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public username: string | null;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true, default: null })
  public lastLoginAt: Date | null;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public socketId: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  public online!: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.sender)
  public messages!: Message[];

  @OneToMany(() => GroupToUser, (groupToUser) => groupToUser.user)
  public joinedGroups!: GroupToUser[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => JoinGroupRequest,
    (joinGroupRequest) => joinGroupRequest.user,
  )
  public sentJoinRequests!: JoinGroupRequest[];

  @OneToMany(() => Friend, (friend) => friend.target)
  public friends!: Friend[];

  @OneToMany(() => FriendRequest, (friendRequest) => friendRequest.target)
  public receivedFriendRequests!: FriendRequest[];

  @OneToMany(() => FriendRequest, (friendRequest) => friendRequest.sender)
  public sentFriendRequests!: FriendRequest[];

  toJSON() {
    return instanceToPlain(this, { enableCircularCheck: true });
  }
}
```

Everything other than the strange error on `Friend.target` is fine.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I've Googled it and haven't found anything helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations

Looks like @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.friends) for friend and for User @OneToMany(() => Friend, (friend) => friend.target)
  public friends!: Friend[];

Comment: @SerhiiZadorozhnyi I don't think so... I've got `TypeError: relatedEntities.forEach is not a function` after reversing these two.

Answer (score 0):

you can try reload the entity from the database after making changes to its relations

```
// Before saving the user entity, reload it from the database
sender = await this.userRepository.findOne(sender.id, {
  relations: ['friends', 'friends.target'],
});

// Then save the user entity as usual
await this.userRepository.save(sender);
```